# Need to port data in sql child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-import

Need to port data in sql table

I have a master table with columns (`masterid, masterdata, year`). Here `masterid` is an identity column.

I have the data for year 2012. I need to same 2012 data for 2013

I could solve the problem by simply running a SQL statement like:

```
INSERT INTO mastertable
    SELECT masterdata, 2013 
    FROM mastertable WHERE Year = 2012
```

I would like to run similar kind of run for child table also.

My child table structure is: (`childid , masterid, childdata`)

Here I have child data for the year 2012, I want to have similar data for year 2013 with proper `masterid` created for master data for the year 2013 in first step.

Preferably I would like to have solution without adding additional temporary columns

Any lead greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Kumar.

Comment: "Here I have child data for the year 2012, I want to have similar data for year 2013 with proper masterid created for master data for the year 2013 in first step."      Its not very clear

Comment: for the year 2013 i have rows created in mastertable. i need to duplicate data in child table with proper master ids created in master table as the child table has reference to master table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to store the links between the 2013 and 2012 records created in the `mastertable` table. If you want to achieve this without adding any additional temporary columns you'll need to use T-SQL.

(I've guessed a type of `varchar(max)` for masterdata as you haven't specified its type).

```
DECLARE @links TABLE ( masterid int, newmasterid int )
DECLARE @mastertemp TABLE ( masterid int, masterdata varchar(max) )

DECLARE @masterid int,
        @masterdata varchar(max)

INSERT INTO @mastertemp
SELECT      masterid,
            masterdata
FROM        mastertable
WHERE       [year] = 2012

WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @mastertemp )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1    @masterid = masterid,
                    @masterdata = masterdata
    FROM            @mastertemp

    INSERT INTO mastertable
    VALUES ( @masterdata, 2013 )

    INSERT INTO @links
    VALUES ( @masterid, SCOPE_IDENTITY() )

    DELETE FROM @mastertemp
    WHERE       masterid = @masterid
END

INSERT INTO childtable
SELECT      l.newmasterid,
            c.childdata
FROM        childtable c
INNER JOIN  @links l ON c.masterid = l.masterid
```

Comment: Your solution is absolutely correct. checking for any option to avoid temp tables and while loops.

Comment: @kumar: as far as i'm aware it's not possible without temp tables or creating temporary columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the `ChildId` is identity column with auto increment

You can wrap them up in function/stored procedure without need of temporary table.

**UPDATED**

```
Declare @Year     int

SET @Year = 2011

INSERT INTO MasterTable 
SELECT masterdata, 2013
FROM mastertable WHERE Year = @Year

INSERT INTO childtable
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), c.childdata
FROM childtable c
WHERE masterid in 
(
   SELECT masterid
   FROM masterTable
   WHERE Year = @Year
)
```

Comment: That won't set the correct `childtable.masterid` values, they'll still be pointing at the 2012 records. What your query is doing is essentially duplicating the `childtable` data already in there.